# Pose tracking with mediapipe with two cameras and receive the same coordinates for corresponding points in both images

Tags: coordinate-transformation, vision

I'm fairly new to computer vision and currently trying to make the following happen, but had no success so far.

My situation: I want to track different landmarks of a person with mediapipe. Tracking with a single camera works fine and also tracking with two cameras at the same time. What I want is to receive the same coordinate from each camera for a point that has been detected. For example: Camera 1 found the landmark of the left shoulder with the x and y coordinates (1,2). For camera 2 the same landmark has obviously different coordinates lets say (2,3). Ideally there is a way to map or transform the coordinates of camera 2 to camera 1.

the following picture shows the camera setup

[Camera setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvMAx.jpg) (I can't post images yet)

So far I've tried to use stereo camera calibration as described here: https://temugeb.github.io/opencv/python/2021/02/02/stereo-camera-calibration-and-triangulation.html. But this doesn't seem to do the trick. I receive a rotation and translation matrix as an output from the calibration, but when I concatenate them to a transformation matrix and multiply it with the coordinates of camera 2, the results don't match with the coordinates of camera 1.

I've also tried to implement planar homography, but since the observed scene isn't limited to a plane, it isn't working well.

The idea behind this is to increase to probability that the landmarks will be detected and use both camera streams to build a full set of coordinates for all desired landmarks.

Is it possible to do what I want to do? If so, what's the name of this process?

I'm really grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.